# Add newline to VBA or Visual Basic 6

Tags: vba, vb6

I want to concatenate two strings with a linebreak between them.

```
st = "Line 1" + newline + "Line2"
```

How do I add a newline to VBA or Visual Basic 6?

Comment: You'll want to do this: [`st = "Line 1" + vbCrLf + "Line2"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Probably because this is very easy to search for. I would argue this Q/A isn't really helpful, as it's well-known/well-documented information.

Comment: Yes a simple Google search for "how do i create a new line in a string vba" returns the answers.  Especially given you answered your own question as a "I'm going to throw this out there as a good searchable answer because it doesn't exist" but in reality it does.  It does exist.

Comment: 4700-20K+ google hits for this on this site alone (depending on how you word it).  I am quite certain MSDN would have the answer as well.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I disagree with the "asked and answered" crowd.  I come to stack overflow not only to find answers, but to find out the best answers.  In this case, it seems that there are no escape sequences in VBA.  Good to know.  While this was an overly simple example ;), there are plenty where I go to stack overflow to look first.   Hopefully my +1 keeps you excited about generating answers for people like myself.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Visual Basic has built-in constants for newlines:

`vbCr` = Chr$(13) = CR (carriage-return character) - used by Mac OS and Apple II family

`vbLf` = Chr$(10) = LF (line-feed character) - used by Linux and Mac OS X

`vbCrLf` = Chr$(13) & Chr$(10) = CRLF (carriage-return followed by line-feed) - used by Windows

`vbNewLine` = the same as `vbCrLf`

Comment: While this is the correct answer, this question has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: @voters instead of downvoting a correct answer, try close voting the question if you think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Doesn't VBA use chr not char?

Comment: @Usagi Updated it to match VBA/VB6. Thank you for your input!

Comment: For a complete documentation, if you want a line jump, equal to Shift + Enter in Word, use Chr(11)

Answer (score 23):

Use this code between two words:

```
& vbCrLf &
```

Using this, the next word displays on the next line.

Comment: `vbNewLine` is preferred because it will select the correct line terminator.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually two ways of doing this:

1. st = "Line 1" + vbCrLf + "Line 2"
2. st = "Line 1" + vbNewLine + "Line 2"

These even work for message boxes (and all other places where *strings* are used).